# Get String From Parent ViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I need to get an NSString from my parent view controller to its child view.

So I have 'ParentView' ----> 'ChildView'

And I need to get the string from ParentView to ChildView. I have tried adding a method which returns a string in my ParentView and calling it like so in the ChildView with no luck.

Doesn't work:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
startDateLbl.text = [vc string];
```

Any help as to how to achieve this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];` will create a new object.

Just giving you a simple code hope you get it

```
ChildViewController *viewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
//here set your label, make sure startDateLbl has getter property
viewController.startDateLbl.text = [vc string];
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to set a property for your string in the child view.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *childString;
```

Then pass your string from the parent view to the child view before or after you push the view onto the stack.

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"];
vc.childString = parentString;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]; // this assumes navController
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although setting the string value only works if you set it after pushing the view.

Comment: No, you can assign the values at any point after you alloc/init your view. You can assign them before or after you push the view. I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the UIViewController type you may have access to the parent View Controller.

self.parentViewController.someString (see UIViewController documentation).